# Map can only have one feature, after user click

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, features

I have a map with a vector layer and Editing tools. I want the map to have only one feature even if the user keeps adding. So I want **the new feature to automatically erase the previous one (if a previous exists)**. That way there is only one feature in the map, the new one that the user adds (using Editing tools)

I tried some things, but I end up erasing the feature, as soon it is added. How can I do this?

Here is my code:

```
myLayer.events.register('featureadded', this, feature_added);   
map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.EditingToolbar(myLayer));

function feature_added(feature){  
   //erase previous features here (?)
   pins.events.unregister('featureadded', this, feature_added);
}
```

I'm using OpenLayers 2.13.1.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing the erase on the `featureadded` event, why not try it attached to the `beforefeatureadded` event (ref: http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.events).

Since this is triggered before the feature is actually added to the layer you should be able to call something along the lines of [`destroyFeatures`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.destroyFeatures) on the layer without it deleting your new feature, since the new feature shouldn't exist yet. Note that I haven't had time to test this!

If that doesn't work, one thing we've done in the past is, when a feature is added, we get the information required about that feature (location, style etc.), then call `destroyFeatures`, which destroys everything, and then just simply redraw it using the information we gathered before we destroyed it again. Its a bit backwards yes but it might be helpful!